# IFS fractal generation using a JPEG or PNG image (Python)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, fractals, ifs

I am looking to program a fractal generator on Python using an Iterated function system.

There are lots of examples and pieces of information with regards to generating fractals online however I can't find any where a .PNG or .JPEG is used as the base/original image. They all begin with drawing or defining their own image coordinates. I have a basic understanding of how to manipulate images using Pillow however I am struggling to incorporate this into an IFS.

Any help on how to begin this, or examples on a simple basis upon which i could build would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is way to broad for SO. The input to a (basic) IFS algorithm is a set of transformation functions, which are usually expressed in matrix form. These matrices can easily be generated from a set of 4-sided polygons: one polygon (usually a square or rectangle) for the outer frame, and subsequent polygons are interpreted as affine transformations of that frame. Extracting those polygons from a bitmap image is _possible_, but it's a rather advanced task, far more complicated than creating the IFS itself.

Comment: (cont) I recommend you just do what everyone else does, and use a GUI (eg in Tkinter) to let the user input the polygons. Alternatively, you could use a vector-based format like SVG to store the polygons, but of course that means you'd need to use something like Inkscape to generate the input data.